# Error while creating SQL query with bind variables - JDBCTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

I am very beginner to Spring - JDBC . 
I am trying to retrieve the employee_id from a table using the query having bind variables and also with IN condition in it .

I'm getting SQLException that

> " invalid column type" -  Caused by:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select
>   employee_id from table_employee where age=:varTwo and marks in
>   (:varOne) and name =:varThree]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004];
>   Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   Invalid column type

Can you please tell , where I'm wrong .

I have tried using the types as Long , Integer , String  but still i'm getting "invalid column type"

age is - NUMBER

marks is - NUMBER

name is - VARCHAR

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("varOne", varOne);
parameters.addValue("varTwo", Long.parseLong(varTwo));
parameters.addValue("varThree", varThree);
Long employeeId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select employee_id from table_employee where age=:varTwo and marks in (:varOne) and name =:varThree" , Long.class , parameters);
```

I should be getting the result of this SQL as the "employee id".

Comment: Looks like you are not using a NamedParameterTemplate - please **[edit]** your question and add the code that initializes your `jdbcTemplate`

Comment: private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 
 @Autowired
 public EmployeeImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
  this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
 }

Comment: I'm simply auto-wiring it.

Comment: And you are auto-wiring a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: No ..... I don't know about that

Comment: If you are not using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` then you can't use named parameters

Comment: Okay . I'll read about that .

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of varOne may be Collection.
When you want to use a variable in SQL query especially with IN, you should make sure the variable is a correct type.

Comment: varTwo  is a List<Long> which is why I've used IN clause . How can I resolve it ?

Comment: NO, you can apply List<Long> to ‘IN’ instead of '=' in SQL. You must made mistake with varOne and varTwo. you can try sql like `select employee_id from table_employee where age=:varOne and name =:varThree and marks in (:varTwo)`, remember make sure the type of varTwo is instance of java.util.Collection, and varOne is a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I was able to proceed further by making the list to string using join method.